# Reusing objects in functions defined in C++ header

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function library in a header file, which includes the following function:

```
// Get a normally distributed float value in the range [0,1].
inline float GetNormDistrFloat()
{
    std::random_device _RandomDevice;
    std::normal_distribution<float> _NormalDistr(0.5, 2.0);

    float val = -1;
    do { val = _NormalDistr(_RandomDevice); } while(val < 0.0f || val > 1.0f);

    return val;
}
```

This works well, however, I don't want to create the `std::random_device` and `std::normal_distribution` objects every time I call this function `GetNormDistrFloat()`.

What is the "best" (correct) way in C++ to deal with this? I tried to just move those two object definitions outside the function, but that led to linker errors. Do I have to create a .cpp file for this header and initialize the objects there?

Comment: `_RandomDevice` is a reserved identifier. Drop the leading underscores.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could mark them as static variables which makes them behave almost like globals but only accessible inside the function:

```
void bar() {
    static Foo foo_instance;
    // Foo gets initialized only once
}
```

The main difference is the initialization. Globals get initialized at startup and static variables at their first access.

You can also make them globals, just make sure you do not define them in a header file, instead declare them as external:

```
// Header file
extern Foo foo_instance;

// Cpp file
Foo foo_instance;
```

Initialization of local static objects is thread-safe, however everything else is not.

Comment: Or add a mutex.

Comment: The local-static solution is no more thread-safe than the global one.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are right but AFAIK the initialization is guaranteed to be thread-safe

Comment: @molbdnilo: The chief problem with the global one is that it suffers from order-of-initialization issues. Globals are constructed in order of declaration within a file, but that's only a partial order (not across source files)

Answer (score 2):

I'm am not a fan of other solutions mentioned here; such as using globals or static locals. For one, state in functions is not a good idea as it's implicit and not obvious when reading code. It also makes things more complicated if you want to use the function from multiple threads. And it also makes testing more complicated. Instead, the "correct" way to handle state is to do the boring thing and create a class:

```
class NormDistrFloatGenerator
{
public:
    NormDistFloatGenerator(const std::random_device& device,
                           const std::normal_distribution<float>& normal)
      : m_device(device)
      , m_normal(normal)
    {}

    float get_float() { // use member variables with same logic as in question }

private:
    std::random_device m_device;
    std::normal_distribution<float> m_normal;
};
```

At least if you write this class, you can test it properly, or use it in multiple threads. You only have to initialize this class once, and then you can repeatedly generate floats. If you really want to have something convenient, you can then do:

```
NormDistFloatGenerator& void makeGlobalFloatGenerator() {
    static NormDistFloatGenerator(std::random_device, std::normal_distribution<float>(0.5, 2.0);
}

// at namespace scope
auto& g_float_generator = makeGlobalFloatGenerator();
```

You can then use `g_float_generator` everywhere. I'd really encourage you to avoid this approach. And even more so avoid the shortcuts others are suggesting.

Comment: Instead of the `device` and the `normal` objects I would take the two floats (0.5, 2.0 in the OP's example) as the parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @Fozi That may well be preferable, I'm not really emphasizing that point because I'm not sure what the best fit is, say in terms of testing requirements, or anything else. I more wanted to just emphasize using a class so I went with the constructor that maps the most directly to the members.

Comment: Nice as the idea may sound, it's a known anti-pattern for Random Number Generators. By duplicating state, you duplicate the number sequences, which effectively makes them non-random.